# Remove configuration files of Déjà Dup, purge not working

Tags: 18.04, backup, snap, deja-dup, duplicity

I want to completely reset deja-dup configuration files.

1. I tried removing and installing again using `snap`, but previous settings are still there after a fresh install (e.g. backup path, folders to ignore, etc).

   ```
   $ sudo snap remove --purge duplicity
   snap "duplicity" is not installed

   $ sudo snap remove --purge deja-dup
   deja-dup removed

   $ sudo snap install --classic deja-dup
   deja-dup 42.6 from Michael Terry (mterry) installed
   ```
2. Also tried looking for `deja-dup` and `duplicity` files afterwards with `find` and got nothing.
3. Removing deja-dup with `apt` does nothing since I didn't use it to install deja-dup.
4. Also note I didn't manually install duplicity, I'm guessing that comes bundled with deja-dup from the snapstore. Anyway tried removing it with apt and snap and said wasn't installed as expected.

Where are these settings located?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

deja-dup stores its settings in gsettings keys. You can see and modify them in `dconf-editor`. The reason purging doesn't remove the settings is because deja-dup is a classic snap, so the configuration isn't in a purge-able place.

[image]