# Déjà Dup does not allow to change google drive account from which restore the files

Tags: restore, deja-dup, google-drive

I had to reinstall Ubuntu and then I wanted to restore the backup I saved in Google Drive (using Deja-dup). It didn't ask me which account, it just said that there weren't any backups to restore. After a while, I noticed that the google account it was using was different from the one in which I have my backup, although I didn't choose any account from which restore the backup (it seems that it was using the account with which I logged in in Ubuntu).

Anyway, it looks like there is no way to change this account from the application. Actually, I've seen a lot of similar questions in this site regarding this same issue. In particular, [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1297217/remove-configuration-files-of-d%C3%A9j%C3%A0-dup-purge-not-working?newreg=d250cd3102334f0baff49093b816495e) has a good answer. It recommends the use of dconf-editor, which I have already downloaded. Unfortunately, this didn't solve the problem, because none of the modifiable settings says anything about the google account deja-dup is using (or maybe I'm just not able to find it?). Can anyone give me a helping hand here?

[Available configurable settings in dconf-editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NXvT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug I experienced is described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/1875255). They basically said that they are not going to fix it since there are some workarounds to this issue. What I did was mounting the google drive account in which my backup is to Nautilus. Then, the files there are accessible through the option "local folder" of deja-dup. I think this is faster an easier than downloading all the files.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem with choosing the account and this is how I solved it (with a workaround):

1. Go to Google Drive
2. Click on "Settings" in the top right corner
3. Go to "Manage apps"
4. Remove access by Déjà Dup Backups (I also removed access by GNOME earlier, but it didn't fix anything and based on what I read it shouldn't change anything, but I'm just putting it out there)
5. Try backing up or restoring with deja-dup again and now it will ask for you to choose and account.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem as you. Having two google accounts configured on my Ubuntu (2020.04.02), I cannot switch Deja Dup to one to another one. Is as always Deja Dup is using the first account configured on Gnome.

The only solution that has helped me is, going to "On-line Accounts" remove my google account. Restart then Deja Dup and will ask now for Google credentials again. Write here the account that you want. After Deja Dup is correctly configured with the desired Google Account, you can set again any other google account on gnome without any issues.

Referring to the answer from @Enrique. Note than if the account was already on gnome on-line accounts, is using the gnome API keys. But if is not, Deja Dup will use its own API keys for handling access to Google Drive. Maybe this can be clue for the problem described in the link provided.